# How can I change the key name in the data when making a post request

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have the following problem:

I want to send my form data to a rest api and the form in my data looks like this:

```
data(){
    return {
        form: {
              ...
              selectedCategoriesRoomCount: {
                 categoryName: '',
                 roomCount: ''
              }
        }
  }
}
```

when I make a post request with axios the json data looks like this:

```
selectedCategoriesRoomCount {
    categoryName: "Business Casual",
    roomCount: "2"
}
```

But I need the key value pair to look like this:

```
selectedCategoriesRoomCount: {
    "Business Casual": "2"
},
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
selectedCategoriesRoomCount['Business Casual'] = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem